# Role based user in multiple blog application

Tags: mongoid, roles, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm building a blogportal where a users `habtm` blogs. I now need to set up a role system where a blog admin can restrict access to "his" blog for e.g hired writers. All blogs have their own subdomain and I'm using Mongoid and Rails 3.2.

What is the "best" way to accomplish this? I should be easy to check the current_user if he can edit this post or if he can manage themes.

Kind of like this:

```
unless current_user.can?(:manage_themes, current_blog)
  redirect_to permission_denied_path
end
```

I guess many of you've done this already and that's why I ask :)

THX